# Cormen Insertion Sort Algo Analysis

Tags: algorithm

[image: Cormen Algo Insertion Sort Analysis]

In Cormen, on page no 47 during analysis of Insertion sort, the no of times the 5th line in pseudo code  gets executed is summation from j=2 to j=n of t-1?
I cannot understand it. Please, if you have read Cormen then help me out with it.

Comment: Write the pseudo code snippet, please.

Comment: Edit your question and write the pseudo code exactly as it's printed in the book. Clearly identify the line you're having trouble understanding. Also include the quote from the book that you don't understand. Expecting us to have the exact edition of "Cormen's book" that you have is a bit unrealistic.

Comment: @JimMischel I am having problem with the value of the  no of times the 5th line gets executed?

Comment: On the first iteration, `i` starts at 1 and goes backward. How many times could the loop possibly be executed? When `j=6`, `i` starts at 5 and works backwards. What is the maximum number of times it can execute? If you answer those two questions, then you should be able to answer the question of how many times the inner loop execute over the entire run of the algorithm. In this case, it helps to assume that the original array is in *descending* order, and you want to sort it into *ascending* order. It also helps to get a deck of cards and walk through the steps by hand with, say, 5 cards.

Comment: @Jjm Mischel I got that.Thanks bro.

Answer (score 1):

I won't give you the answer, but I'll give you some hints to help you find the answer yourself.

On the first iteration, `i` starts at 1 and goes backward. How many times could the loop possibly be executed?

When `j=6`, `i` starts at 5 and works backwards. What is the maximum number of times it can execute?

If you answer those two questions, then you should be able to answer the question of how many times the inner loop execute over the entire run of the algorithm.

In this case, it helps to assume that the original array is in descending order, and you want to sort it into ascending order. It also helps to get a deck of cards and walk through the steps by hand with, say, 5 cards.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with a simpler line - line 2 for example:

It is going to be executed **1** time per iteration of the **for** loop. The **for** loop iterates between **j = 2 and n**, so line 2 can be represented by the summation:

[image: summation]

Using summation properties we know that

[image: summation].

Now for the while loop on line 5: this time we don't know how many times this line will be executed since it depends on j and the elements in the array as @Jim mentioned.

In order to simplify the process with analysis we introduce a variable [image: tj], which shows the number of times that line 5 is executed per iteration depending on the value of **j**. So we can say that line 5 will be executed [image: tj] times per **for** loop iteration. Hence we can represent it by the summation:

[image]